# Need to run a .bin file, but same error keeps coming up

Tags: bash

I have a `.bin` file that needs to run. I'm trying to start it through the Terminal, and I keep getting an error that says:

```
LSB 3.0 or higher not found
```

I can't get to than internet at my school without running the program. How can I get the LSB files so I can run the program?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Ubuntu Forum tread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1458140.html) you need to have installed the LSB Runtime installed.

To install **LSB v4.0** enter the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-core && lsb-languages
```

Also you can install it from Synaptic or downloading the binary files from the repositories. But the *fastest and security and simple* method is the one mentioned above using `apt`.